# Codeigniter: form validation not working in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[8]|max_length[20]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim|matches[password]');
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', "That email address already exists.");
$this->form_validation->set_message('min_length[8]', "The password length is too short.");
```

May i know why doesn't the password part works, however the email part work.

Whenever i try to enter a password with a length less than 8 the form will still get submitted and the information are still inserted into my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password field names are not unique.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[8]|max_length[20]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim|matches[password]');
```

Change it to something like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[8]|max_length[20]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password', 'required|trim|matches[password]');
```